# can't solve this recurrence, please help

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

Give a closed form for this:
T(1) = 1
T(N) = T(n/2) + log(n)

Anyone can show me how to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the asymptotic behavior of the recurrence $T(n)=4T(\frac{n}{2})+n^2$ by using substitution method](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319414/finding-the-asymptotic-behavior-of-the-recurrence-tn-4t-fracn2n2-by)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n = 2^m$,
this becomes
$T(2^n) 
=T(2^{n-1})+\log(2^n) 
=T(2^{n-1})+n\log(2) 
$.

Letting
$T(2^n) = s(n)$,
we get
$s(n) = s(n-1)+n\log 2
$.

You should be able to solve this.

Another way is to
repeatedly apply the recurrence:

$\begin{array}\\
T(n)
&= T(n/2)+\log(n)\\
&= T(n/4)+\log(n/2)+\log(n)\\
&= T(n/8)+\log(n/4)+\log(n/2)+\log(n)\\
&= T(n/2^k)+\log(n/2^{k-1})+...+\log(n/2)+\log(n)\\
\end{array}
$

Apply until
$2^k \ge n > 2^{k-1}
$,
or
$k = \lceil \log_2(n) \rceil -1$.

The sum of logs is,
where
$m = \lceil \log_2(n) \rceil -1
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{m} \log(n/2^k)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m}( \log(n)-\log(2^k))\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m}( \log(n)-k\log(2))\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\log(n)-\sum_{k=0}^{m}k\log(2)\\
&=(m+1)\log(n)-m(m+1)\log(2)/2\\
&=(m+1)(\log(n)-(m+1)\log(2)/2)\\
&=(m+1)(\log(n)-\lceil \log_2(n) \rceil\log(2)/2)\\
&\approx(m+1)(\log(n)-\lceil \log(n) \rceil/2)\\
&\approx(m+1)\log(n)/2)\\
&\approx\log^2(n)\log(2)/2\\
\end{array}
$